# symbolic link binary with targeted directory

Tags: unix, ln

I have a binary which loads assets with relatives paths, and I would like to put a link in /usr/bin.

I have tried `ln -s ~/game_directory/game /usr/bin/game`.

It launches my binary but can't load my assets because it doesn't find the folder ./assets obviously.

There is any solution for that?