# Link a binary to execute from it's orignal directory

Tags: c, assets, symlink

I have a program written in C. It's directory structure is like this:

```
root/
    program.sh
    textures/
        texture1.png
```

`program.sh` imports textures in a way like: `load_textures("./textures/texture1.png")` (relative paths). Hence, the program only works whenever I execute `program.sh` from the `root` directory.

I want to create a link to `program.sh` such that, whenever I execute the link, I am able to execute the `program.sh` from the root directory. In other words, I want to execute `program.sh` from outside the root directory.

Now, I would prefer a solution to do this without changing the source code (if there is a way), otherwise, how would you recommend that I open files/textures in C, given the current scenario?

Had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433262/symbolic-link-binary-with-targeted-directory), but it's unanswered.

Comment: Are you just looking to change the current working directory of the program when executed from the link?

Comment: The program is using a relative path to the assets. So, if I change the directory, it will work. But I want to come back to the directory from where I was before, after the execution.

Comment: You can do that with a simple shell script: `pushd` into your desired directory, execute the program from there, and `popd`.

Comment: So, I make a wrapper-ish script, using `pushd` and `popd` to execute the program?

Comment: Yep. You can even pass the command-line arguments given to the script into your program. I mean, you _can_ do this from a separate C program, but it's not worth it.

Comment: Just a bit of googling about `pushd` and `popd`, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31391814/8726146). Thanks a lot, fellow Sir. :D

Comment: Would you post an answer, so that I can mark it as solved, and you get that sweet karma? Or, do I just flag the question as a duplicate (:P).

Comment: Sure, I'll make a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it became clear from comments, the goal was to execute the program from a different directory, but with the program's current working directory pointing to its own directory.

While this *can* be done in C (in a POSIX system, as assumed due to the `.sh` extension, via a combination of the `chdir` and `execvp` syscalls), it's much more easily achieved in a wrapper shell script, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

pushd /path/to/executable
./program.sh $@
popd
```